# Calculate dynamic cell height for a horizontal UICollectionView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am creating a UI based on horizontally scrolling cards. All set and one but, some cards are now bigger (more content) than the others. In this case, I guess my solution won't work because I calculate the flow layout size like this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width-30)/2,(collectionView.frame.size.height);
}
```

This restricts cell's height. Is it even possible to have a dynamic height of UICollectionViewCells for horizontal layout? No clues found on the web. Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (CGSize)calculateSizeForSizingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)sizingCell width:(CGFloat)width {
CGRect frame = sizingCell.frame;
frame.size.width = width;
sizingCell.frame = frame;
[sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
[sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

CGSize size = [sizingCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize
                    withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                          verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel];
return size;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the height of each texts inside collection view cell dynamically.

See below code and update according to your requirements.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableDictionary *currentObject = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGFloat cvWidth = (collectionView.frame.size.width-30)/2;
    CGSize rect;

    CGFloat heightOfText = [self getTextHeightFromString:[currentObject valueForKey:@"yourKeyName"] ViewWidth:cvWidth WithPading:10];

    CGFloat heightOfSecondText = [self getTextHeightFromString:[currentObject valueForKey:@"yourSecondKeyName"] ViewWidth:cvWidth WithPading:10];

    //get height of each and every text and calculate total height

    rect.width = cvWidth;
    rect.height = heightOfText + heightOfSecondText;

    return rect;

}

- (CGFloat)getTextHeightFromString:(NSString *)text ViewWidth:(CGFloat)width WithPading:(CGFloat)padding
{
    CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFontName" size:16]} // change font size accordingly
                                     context:nil];

    return rect.size.height + padding;
}
```